# Weblogic cache replication with clusters

Tags: weblogic, rmi, ehcache, weblogic-10.x

Is it possible to implement a cache in weblogic (10.3.5.0) which is accessible on every instance of a cluster ?
Does weblogic API offers some API with RMI who offers this possibility ?

Is there a framework like ehcache who offers this possibility ?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Coherence can handle this situation and it comes bundled with WebLogic 10.3.5.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/coherence/CreateCoherenceServers.html

"Coherence servers (also known as Coherence data nodes) are stand-alone cache servers, dedicated JVM instances responsible for maintaining and managing cached data."